# I can't figure out the syntax to throw the exception for the denominator as a 0 for the rational class

Tags: java, exception

I am getting an error for both the rational syntax and the exception syntax when I try to compile the class. Here are some examples of the methods that are supposed to throw the error.

```
/**
 * Negate a rational number r
 * 
 * @return a new rational number that is negation of this number -r
 */    
public Rational negate()
{               
    // CHANGE THE RETURN TO SOMETHING APPROPRIATE
return new Rational ((-1*numerator),denominator); 
}


/**
 * Invert a rational number r 
 * 
 * @return a new rational number that is 1/r.
 */    
public Rational invert()
{               
    // CHANGE THE RETURN TO SOMETHING APPROPRIATE
if (numerator == 0) { 

    throw new ZeroDenominatorException( ); 

} 

    return new Rational (denominator,numerator);


}
```

Comment: The logic in your `invert()` method looks correct to me; what's the question?  Note that you probably also want to swap the numerator and denominator, since they switch when taking the inverse.

Comment: The compiler error will tell you the exact line and cursor position of the syntax error. Where does that point to?

Comment: add `throws ZeroDenominatorException` to your `invert` method signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `ZeroDenominatorException` is a checked exception, you need to add `throws ZeroDenominatorException` to your `invert` method signature (or whichever methods throw checked exceptions):-

```
public Rational invert() throws ZeroDenominatorException
```